# adding vertical divider on main menu

Tags: html, css

How can I add vertical divider after the li element on the main menu?

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" > نبذه عنا </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> اكادمية بوذيب للفروسيه </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> اسطابلات بوذيب </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> المركز الاعلامي </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> اتصل بنا </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> اكثر <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">  </a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the site I want to fix: [the  site](http://dryousryelsafty.com/sayed/home1/)

And this is the image I want the main menu to be like: [the image](http://upbeatdigital.com/works/butheeb/)

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you could try this by giving border to sides, but nav items have more height than vertical line that you want to give, then you can try `<pseudo:before>` to achive this

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 15px);
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:last-child>a:after,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:first-child>a:after{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: i want to remove the vertical before home and after the  last child

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```css
ul li{
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0 8px;
  border-right:2px solid gray;
}
ul li:last-child{
  border:none;
  }

a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" > نبذه عنا </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> اكادمية بوذيب للفروسيه </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> اسطابلات بوذيب </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> المركز الاعلامي </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> اتصل بنا </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> اكثر <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a></li>
      </ul>
```